# Deleted bad question has an "ok" answer

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

#### Context:

I have answer a ["Give me the code"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41711954/6560478) question.
It's been a long time ago, because it was Something that I have been ask before.

The long version of the question for not premium user:

> How could I create a winform control that look like a Application dock?
> [Insert image of mac application dock]

As answer I gave a link to the solution and offer the code of an alternative.

#### Issue:

It's the second time after the deletion of the question that someone, ask me directly how to do it. And every time I have to find the link to this question in my mail. Copy the content and send it to the asker.

In order to make this answer usefull to SO, what are my possibilities?

- Ask for undeletion of this shame?
- Try to create a valid self answered question?
- Create a documentation post?

I can't figure out a valid way to Self-"Giv me de Codez".

In documentation the 1rst part of the answer, the link to the correct solution will be a little short. And the second part seems too complexe to be a documentation.

And I don't feel like this question can be edit into anything ok.

Comment: How are people *finding* this question and determining that you answered it, without actually being able to see the answer?

Comment: @CodyGray I think OP is suggesting that new questions are being posted asking the same thing, not that people are finding the deleted QA.

Comment: As I ask many question in one post, I don't know which one you re downvoting. I will assume: Downvote = This answer is not worthy. And I can't totaly disagree.

Answer (score 4):

> I can't figure out a valid way to Self-"Giv me de Codez".

Correct, Stack Overflow is not the place to share user controls and other things you've built, *unless* they're relevant to an on-topic question.

You shouldn't answer questions asking for off-site resource ("looking for a user control that does so-and-so"), or worse, to write something for the asker.

Go write a blog, put the code on GitHub and provide support there.

Comment: Ok, even if I won't do it for now. This seems to be best thing to do. So is not a place to share code but a Q&A site. And this question is not on topics. If someone look for this kind of thing they will be better on a sharing code site and not on SO.

Comment: Yes, that's the consensus. We don't want to become another CodeProject, full of half-working example projects that don't really work in production and aren't supported by anyone but crickets.

Comment: *"We don't want to become another CodeProject, full of half-working example projects that don't really work in production and aren't supported by anyone but crickets."* Wait, [haven't we already become that](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation)?